# What makes a single photon light source different from classical light sources?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

I ask this question in terms of the hardware that's used to build single photon sources. How is it fundamentally different from other coherent or chaotic light sources? What is it about these sources that causes the light to be emitted in its more quantized form as compared to the wave like nature that we end up observing in lasers and thermal light sources?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_source discusses this some.

Comment: It’s Always emitted in quantized form. That’s what light is made of, billions of individual photons.